# differential operator on a finite dimensional span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of real functions with basis $x^ie^{4x}$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$ for some positive integer $n$.
Define $T: V \to V$ as $T(f)=f+f'$ where $f'$ is the usual derivative.

Then, the questions are as below.

(a)Prove $T$ is surjective

(b)Find all real eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors for $T$.

(c)Define $T_c=cf'+f$. Find all real $c$ such that $T_c$ is not surjective.

For (a), T has a matrix representation with respect to the given basis as a lower triangular matrix with nonzero diagonal entries. Thus it is in fact bijective.

For (b), I think it is just an ordinary differential equation and the only eigenvalue is $5$ with an eigenvector $e^{4x}$.

For (c), after calculations, I think the only answer is $c=-1/4$, in order to make the determinant of $T_c$ zero.

Are my arguments correct? Could anyone please give me a feedback?

Comment: Yes, they seem correct.